# Why do my 'small' images appear poor quality and of low resolution when they aren't

Tags: image, small-image

I am trying to figure out the optimal size for the 'small' images (the one that will appear on a category page) but no matter what size or resolution I make them, they appear as low resolution - I have tried them from as high as 2000 x 2000 px - down to 250 x 250 px and they are always saved as optimized for web through Photoshop

Comment: To add to Fabian Schmenglers answer, depending on your theme you may also have a css height & width on the img tag, which may distort the image.

Answer (score 1):

All images in the frontend are automatically resized based on theme settings. The sizes are defined in `etc/view.xml` of the theme and are different for various areas, like the category grid.

#### For example: [luma/etc/view.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/etc/view.xml#L27-L29)

```
<image id="category_page_grid-1" type="small_image">
    <width>240</width>
    <height>300</height>
</image>
```